# Why are shutdown scripts not guaranteed?

Tags: google-compute-engine

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) it says that shutdown scripts are only run on a best effort basis and that they are not guaranteed to run. I'm wondering what conditions these would be where they wouldn't run?

**Edit**

As AndyJ pointed out, the documentation I linked to describes when the script is *supposed* to be run. To clarify, I have read all of that but it seemed to me that the lack of guarantee to run included the conditions in which it normally is supposed to.

So, to better phrase my question, is the script guaranteed to run in the conditions the documentation says it runs it, or is that only when it **should** and not necessarily when it **will**?

Comment: The shutdown script generates an exception, hangs in an infinite loop, or runs so long that the resources have disappeared.

Comment: That's odd, 5 people upvoted your question and yet none of them read the documentation you linked to. You'd have thought individuals so interested in the answer would have put some basic effort in!

Answer (score 2):

They address this in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#specifications) you linked to.

> Shutdown script invocation
>
> Shutdown scripts execute when an instance is scheduled to restart or terminate. **There are many ways to restart or terminate an instance but only some actions will trigger the shutdown script to run. A shutdown script will run when:**
>
> An instance is deleted using the instances().delete. request. This includes any tools or scripts that use the API, such as the Google Cloud Platform Console and gcloud compute.
>   An instance is shut down through the console or the instances.stop() method.
>   An instance is restarted or shut down through a request to the guest operating system, such as a sudo shutdown or sudo reboot.
>
> Note: If your shutdown script requires a network connection, we recommend shutting down your instance using this method because of a known issue with network connectivity loss. The issue primarily affects instances that have been shut down outside of the guest operating system.
>   The shutdown script will not run if the instance is reset using instances().reset.
>
> Shutdown script running time
>
> When a shutdown script is invoked, it has a limited time period to run, between when the request is made to shut down or restart the instance, to when the instance is actually terminated. During this period, Compute Engine will attempt to run your shutdown script but if the script takes longer than this time period to complete, the instance will automatically terminate and all running tasks are killed. If you shut down or restart an instance by making a request to the guest OS (e.g. running sudo shutdown) the limit does not apply.
>
> In general, we recommend that your shutdown script finishes running within this time period, so that the operating system has time to complete its shutdown, including flushing buffers to disk.
>
> For more information on this time limit, see Shutdown period.

Comment: I have already read and understand the section you quoted. Please see my updated question.